# When will dpkg delete directories?

Tags: debian, dpkg

In Debian Jessie's `/etc/cron.d/` there's a file called `.placeholder`, the contents of which claim:

```
# DO NOT EDIT OR REMOVE
# This file is a simple placeholder to keep dpkg from removing this directory
```

Now, .placeholder files are [mentioned](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/placeholder-files-668250/) various [places](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756817), but under what conditions would one be necessary? When would dpkg decide to delete an empty directory under `/etc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably left over from historical behaviour in `dpkg`. Nowadays removal is handled in [`remove.c`](http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.18.2/src/remove.c/?hl=431#L431), and directories are removed only if they are empty and the current package (being removed) is the only one using them (this is determined in [`help.c`](http://sources.debian.net/src/dpkg/1.18.2/src/help.c/?hl=272#L243), in `dir_is_used_by_others()` and `dir_is_used_by_pkg()`).

Looking at the `cron` package reveals the placeholders were introduced in 2004 as a remedy to bug [#217760](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=217760); it's possible that at the time, `dpkg` didn't check things as thoroughly as it does now, in such a way that if removing a package caused a directory to become empty, that directory would be deleted as well. So `cron` would install `/etc/cron.d`, but no file inside that directory; then another package would drop a file there, and removing that package would delete the file and also the directory (since it then became empty). This broke `cron`, so to avoid the bug a placeholder was added.